# Interrupting loops

Tags: c, arduino

I'm working on an Arduino lighting project using rbg LEDs to create customizable colors. I'm using the [IRremote](http://z3t0.github.io/Arduino-IRremote/) library to change "modes" with the LEDs.

Here's my program:

```
#include <IRremote.h>

const int RECV_PIN = 7;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;
int redpin = 9;
int greenpin = 10;
int bluepin = 5;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn();
  irrecv.blink13(true);
  pinMode(redpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluepin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)){
    Serial.println("Before it checks for signal");

    if (results.value == 0xFFE21D) { //'TITLE' button
      Serial.println("'TITLE' signal detected, before fade starts");

      //Fades through colors

      int i;

      //green to red
      for (i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
        analogWrite(redpin, i);
        analogWrite(greenpin, 255 - i);
        analogWrite(bluepin, 0);
        delay(1);
        Serial.println("Green to red");
      }

      //red to blue
      for (i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
        analogWrite(redpin, 255 - i);
        analogWrite(greenpin, 0);
        analogWrite(bluepin, i);
        delay(1);
        Serial.println("Red to blue");
      }

      //blue to green
      for (i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
        analogWrite(redpin, 0);
        analogWrite(greenpin, i);
        analogWrite(bluepin, 255 - i);
        delay(1);
        Serial.println("Blue to green");
      }
    }

    if (results.value == 0xFFD22D) { //'MENU' button
      Serial.println("'MENU' button detected");

      //LED red
      analogWrite(redpin, 255);
      analogWrite(greenpin, 0);
      analogWrite(bluepin, 0);
    }

    if (results.value == 0xFF52AD) { //'ON/OFF' button
      Serial.println("'STOP' button detected");

      //Stops
      analogWrite(redpin, 0);
      analogWrite(greenpin, 0);
      analogWrite(bluepin, 0);

      Serial.println("After LED stops");
    }

    Serial.println("After program");
    irrecv.resume();
  }
}
```

Inside `void loop()`, I have three `if()` statements. The first one checks for a certain button press on the remote, and the LED fades from green to red to blue to green (this only executes once, but that's a problem for another thread).

The second `if()` statement checks for a different button press, and the LED turns red. I plan on having several of these for different colors.

The third `if()` statement checks for the ON/OFF button and turns the LED off.

I am able to switch between these. **The problem is that once the first `if()` statement executes and the LED fades through, I am unable to switch to either of the other statements until it ends.**

I know that once the first statement is executed, it doesn't check for signals until it's done, but I cannot think of a way around how I did it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your question is ... but I suspect the answer might be to split your code into [subroutines](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/561/Syllabus/2-C/subroutine.html).  Create an `onOff()` function.  A `doFade()` function.  And so on.  Then *call* whichever function (or combination of functions) you need to in response to specific `response` values.

Comment: I would put the fade in/out code into a non-blocking co-routine. Those are tricky in C but can be done. In short, you keep static variables of what the current settings are and what the target settings are; inside the loop you check the buttons, change the target values if needed, then call the co-rountine to do a single fading step and return to the loop.

Comment: @paulsm4 I come from JS where that's what I'm used to. I create a function and call it when I need it. C has been a bit of learning for me, and that never came to mind. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to implement a simple state machine. For that, you need to switch your loop / if statements around. In pseudocode:

```
int mode; // 0: green, 1: red and so on
while(true) {
    // check button presses
    if(buttonpress) {
        mode = mode+1;
    }
    if(mode==1)
        make_leds_more_green();
    else if(mode==2)
        make_leds_more_red();
    //...
    delay(1);
}
```

Comment: Yup - exactly the kind of thing I was trying to say: a) "Actions" should be moved out of "main()" and put into separate C functions.  b) The "while()" loop reads input and  calls the appropriate action (or actions).  c) I assumed that "response.value" pretty much *WAS* the "state" ... but you're correct, that's not necessarily the case.

Comment: I had no idea what a state machine was before, this was extremely helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Tstenner's state machine is one way to go. I'll outline another below, but the basic idea is that you need the loop to continue as you fade the LEDs in/out in single steps. Here's my co-routine approach:

```
int pins[3] = { redpin, greenpin, bluepin };
int current[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };
int target[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };

led_tick() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    if (current[i] == target[i]) continue;
    if (current[i] < target[i]) {
      current[i] += 1;
    } else {
      current[i] -= 1;
    }
    analogWrite(pins[i], current[i]);
  }
}

loop() {
  // handle buttons, change target values
  led_tick();
  delay(1);  // making this non-blocking would be even better

}
```

Comment: Having one function to handle the color fading is certainly more elegant than my approach. I was more focused on handling the button presses during the color changes, but a combination of our answers should answer the question.

Comment: Yes, I like state machines for a lot of embedded stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a hand made non-blocking

1. Remove the `for`
2. Remove the `delay`
3. Use `millis()` with period

```
#define DELAY  5000

int step;

void greenToRed() {
    // Non blocking, only check if the waiting period passed
    if(changeToRed && millis() > time_1 + DELAY){
        // Update the time
        time_1 = millis();
        // Update the step
        step -= 1;

        analogWrite(redpin, 255 - step);
        analogWrite(greenpin, step);
        analogWrite(bluepin, 0);
        Serial.println("Green to red");

        // Finish condition
        if(step =< 0) {
            changeToRed = 0;
        }
    }
}

void loop() {
    if (results.value == 0xFFE21D) {
        changeToRed = 1;
        step = 255;
    }
    greenToRed();
}
```

Comment: This seems like the easiest solution to understand to me, but where is `changeToRed` defined?

Comment: @Joe Pigott Just swap the `loop` method with `greenToRed` or add a method declaration `void greenToRed();` before `loop`. I have edited the post